# Network error when trying to install styled components via npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, styled-components

**Hi guys, I have am trying to get my environment set up. I have started a React project with**

```sh
npx create-react-app PROJECTNAME
```

**I am now looking into using [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/). However when I attempt to install it with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) using this command**

```sh
npm i --save styled-components
```

**I get this error:**

```sh
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/styled-components failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1123:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nicho\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-05T23_33_02_048Z-debug-0.log
```

**I am not using a proxy and everything else is working fine with my network.**

Answer (score 0):

go to the react app directory by using these terminal command : cd PROJECTNAME

Comment: This was done in the react app directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).